# Ionic v2 since one made release apk http and https requests don't work

Tags: android, http, ionic-framework, ionic2, release

Since I once build a release apk with ionic v2 with the command:

```
ionic run android --release
```

I cannot make any http request (not even when I just use the debug apk with: `ionic run android`)

I've read that a signed android apk (release) need certificates that it trusts on client and server side.
I've created a keystore and with a valid SHA1-Fingerprint and it still don't work... any ideas?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I keep having this issue forever and do not know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Deploy a app you still need to sign the app.

App deployment has nothing to do with if a app is released or not.

You can follow the following [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html) when deploying.

In terms of http request not working ?

Have you added whitelisting ?

have you added  `<access origin="*"/>` to config.xml

Comment: yeah I know how to publish the app but I just signed it so I could receive results from google because I am using their API.

And yes I have added almost everything to my config.xml
`<access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>`
Even `<allow-navigation href="*" />`

Comment: @HartHerbert from google ? I have developed with Google Analytics, you can still get results with a emulator or deploying to a device

Comment: Yeah I know but if you are using the googlemaps cordova plugin you need to sign your app, thats why.

Comment: You should rather post a question googlemaps cordova plugin then

Comment: no because I now deinstalled everything and it still can't do any requests..
I always get `Response with status: 0 for URL: null`

Comment: Then your questions is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367286/ionic-2-http-get-issue